# How can I replicate Elasticsearch data to azure synapse?

Tags: elasticsearch, azure-synapse

I know Elasticsearch can be used as a data source in Databricks. Can data be ingested directly from Elasticsearch (on-prem) into the Azure Synapse architecture?

Comment: refer https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/elasticsearch-sync-azuresynapse.rst

Answer (score 0):

Using **CData Sync**, a third-party tool, you can replicate Elasticsearch data to Azure Synapse. To add a replication destination, navigate to the Connections tab.

1. Click Add Connection.
2. Select Azure Synapse as a destination.

[image]

3. Enter the necessary connection properties. To connect to Azure Synapse, provide authentication properties (see below) and set the following properties to connect to a Azure Synapse database:

   - Server: The server running Azure. You can find this by logging into the Azure portal and navigating to `Azure Synapse Analytics -> Select your database -> Overview -> Server name`.
   - Database: The name of the database, as seen in the Azure portal on the Azure Synapse Analytics page.

Using SQL Password Authentication
To authenticate to Microsoft SQL Server using standard authentication, set the following:

- User: The username provided for authentication with Azure.
- Password: The password associated with the authenticating user.

4. Click Test Connection to ensure that the connection is configured properly.

[image]

5. Click Save Changes.

Then, you need to configure the Elastic connection.

Follow this [third-party tutorial](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/elasticsearch-sync-azuresynapse.rst) by **cdata** do accomplish the remaining task. This should work.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the answer. My employer does not have a subscription for the c-data tool, I was looking for an open-source or code-based approach.